# Is it OK to install CDO 1.21 with Exchange Server 2010 SP3/ Windows Server 2012?

Tags: exchange-server, windows-server-2012, mapi, cdo.message

We are upgrading our server to Windows 2012 from 2003.
Our application use CDO 1.21 and MAPI to send mails, I know I have to use SMTP/ OOM/AWS. At this late stage I don't want to do make changes in our programs right now - there are 80+ :)

When I am going to MS site to download CDO 1.21, Windows 2102/Exchange Server 2010 SP3 is not specified under supported platforms.

I am able to download CDO 1.21 for Win 2012. But now when I am connecting via MAPI, System is throwing error:

> The information store could not be opened. [MAPI 1.0 - [MAPI_E_LOGON_FAILED(80040111)]]

MAPI Code :

```
   Set objMAPI = New MAPI.Session
  objMAPI.Logon ShowDialog:=False, NewSession:=False, ProfileInfo:=gobjINI.gstrExchangeServer & vbLf & gobjINI.gstrProfile

'Add a new mesage to the OUtbo Messages Collection
Set objMSG = objMAPI.Outbox.Messages.Add
```

Error is thrown on third line: `Set objMSG = objMAPI.Outbox.Messages.Add`.

Comment: Yes, it is Ok to install it on Windows 2010 or 2012.

Comment: Thanks again for answering this. I am able to download and install CDO 1.21 for Win 2012 server. Now when i am trying to connect to MAPI, i am getting error as specified above(In question description). I did some research but not able to get the right answer...can you please take a look at the error.

Comment: So what is the error? I do not see any errors in your question.

Comment: Please find the error in question description, i missed saving it.

Comment: Make sure your app is running as the domain user who owns the mailbox in question.

Comment: I checked it, its running under same domain user.

Comment: You can try to open a support case with Microsoft...